# Returning a private vector

Tags: c++, oop, vector, iterator, private

I have a class with a private attribute that is a vector. What is the best way of doing a getter function?

1. Return the whole vector: `vector<char*> getNames() { return names; }`

   - Would this return a copy or a pointer? Would this be accessible since its private?
2. Return the iterator: `vector<char*>::iterator getNames() { return names.begin(); }`
3. Make the vector public

   - I know this is bad practice for OOP, just listing options.

Comment: Note that option 2 can work but only if you provide a way to access the `end()` iterator as well, or consumers won't know when to stop iterating -- and you'd probably want to use `vector<char*>::const_iterator` instead so that consumers can't modify elements. And on that note, why aren't you using `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: @cdhowie Even `const_iterator` (or returning a const reference) only prevents the pointers themselves from being modified, not the strings they point to.

Comment: @T.C. Indeed, and that will still be the case with the top voted answer. A vector of strings really is the best approach because a `const std::string` can't be modified like a `char * const` can.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm updating some old code, so I'm changing the vectors before I mess with string. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Does the caller need the whole `vector`?  Would `const char* getName(unsigned i) const;` suffice? Easier to maintain const correctness and encapsulation.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Yes the caller will need the vector to be able to iterate through it.

Answer (score 7):

Return by `const vector<char*>&`. It makes sure it won't be modified outside and it doesn't make a copy.

Comment: so it would be `const vector<char*>& getNames() {return names;}`?

Comment: @Sorescale You should probably make the function `const` as well, like e.g. `const vector<char*>& getNames() const { ... }`

Comment: That doesn't prevent people from modifying the names themselves. `getNames()[0][0] = '\0';`

Comment: @T.C Well, that's true, but I don't think there is a good way around without changing char* to something else though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually using a `vector<char *>` internally, the only way to ensure that the user won't modify the names (without an ugly and obvious `const_cast`) would be returning a `vector<const char *>` by value:

```
vector<const char *> getNames() const { return {names.begin(), names.end()}; }
```

or, pre-C++11:

```
vector<const char *> getNames() const { return vector<const char *>(names.begin(), names.end()); }
```

Returning a `vector<char *>`, either by value or by const reference, would prevent the user from modifying your vector itself, but not the contents of the strings it point to.

It's much better to use a `vector<std::string>`, in which case you can simply return a const reference.